# cast value NSCFDictionary (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I do not know how to cast value from NSCFDictionary in swift.
I have the following error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x193baa5d8) to 'PFUser' (0x100811780)

Any help really appreciated.

Regards.

CODE:

```
func logUserData()
{

    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, user, error) -> Void in


        if error != nil
        {
            print(error)
        }
        else
        {

            print("fetched user: \(user)")
            let fbAccessToken1 = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
            print("fbAccessToken1: \(fbAccessToken1)")


            //correct?
            PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(self.currentUser!, withAccessToken: fbAccessToken1) {
                (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if (succeeded != false) {
                    print("Woohoo, the user is linked with Facebook!")
                }
            }


            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind adding the code in which you declare this value above?

Comment: I am actually trying to introduce the Facebook token obtained via the classic FBSDK in order to identify and create a Parse User. And I get the mentioned error.
(I am a beginner)

Comment: Why do you think you can cast `user` to `PFUser`? `user` appears to be an `NSDictionary` obtained from Facebook. That isn't remotely close to being a `PFUser`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I realized I called the user that is fetched instead of the "current user" var.. It's now corrected but it does not solve my problem in trying to link an already connected user to Parse using the Facebook token. 
I believe what I've written above is the right formula but it seems like I'm missing something. 
(Note: I do not use Parse login auth but FBSDK) 
Here is Parse doc: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-linking
Following my edits I now have the following error:  " fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
"

Comment: Add info:  I already created my constant:
    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

Comment: I really hope this time I will finish by having a solution to my problem despite being a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very very unlikely that you can *cast* directly to PFUser. Casting is only supported for closely related types, like NSNumber and Int.

Most likely you have a class PFUser that can be initialised with an init method that takes some kind of dictionary as a parameter. If that is the case, the CFDictionary and NSDictionary are basically the same thing.

If that is not the case, then you need to write code yourself that creates a PFUser and fills it with data that you extract manually from the NSDictionary.

Comment: 3rd option is what I did. 
Thanks for your precisions!  (just a tip:  next time type some code including an example if you know that the request comes from a beginner)